# Bottom Up Makeheap Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, heap

I've been learning about how to construct a heap using the bottom up makeheap **algorithm**. I was wondering if someone could tell me if the below is correct?

So the heap has these values: [10, 3, 4, 7, 8, 12]

so I did this:-

[image: picture]

Are the steps I took correct? Is this how the makeheap algorithm would sort an array? This is a algorithm based question related to programming a makeheap algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not bottom-up method.
At first you have to order bottom subheaps - (3,7,8) -> (8,7,3) and (4,12)->(12,4). Then you can order top subheap (10,8,12)->(12,8,10)